# How to fetch an associated model's last record to prevent N+1 queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, associations

I have a model `Invoice` which `has_many` `Payments` and a model `Payment` that `belongs_to` `Invoice`.

We export Invoice data monthly in batches, and we need each Invoice's last Payment.

In our view we are currently doing `Invoice.payments.last` once for each Invoice that we are exporting, and I was asked to prevent N+1 queries.

I don't understand if I should add this query in the controller or in the Invoice model, or if it should be a `has_one :last_payment` association or a scope.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of payments per invoice is relatively small you can just include/eager_load/preload the association:

```
invoices = Invoice.includes(:payments)
invoices.each do |i|
  puts i.payments.last.amount # no n+1 query
end
```

However this will load all the associated records into memory at once. This can cause performance problems.

One a very performant read optimization would be to add foreign key column to the invoices table and a belongs_to association which you can use when eager loading:

```
class AddLatestPaymentToInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :invoices, :latest_payment, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :payments }
  end
end
```

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments, after_add: :set_latest_invoice!
  belongs_to :latest_payment,
    class_name: 'Payment'

  private
  def set_latest_payment(payment)
    update_columns(latest_payment_id: payment.id)
  end
end
```

```
invoices = Invoice.includes(:latest_payment)
invoices.each do |i|
  puts i.latest_payment.amount # no n+1 query
end
```

The cost is an additional UPDATE query per record inserted. It can be optimized by using a DB trigger instead of an [association callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/association_basics.html#association-callbacks).

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a lot to work with!